# How to access nested JSON object in ReactJS State?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have state:

```
{
  studentId: 1,
  studentName: "Student",
  religion: {
    religionId: 1,
    religionName: "RELIGION"
  }
}
```

How to access religionName in react?

I have tried access my student state like this:

```
const {studentState} = useContext(StudentContext);

return (
 <div>
  {studentState.studentId}
  {studentState.studentName}
  {studentState.religion.religionName}
 </div>
);
```

Undifined result when using `{studentState.religion.religionName}`

Comment: Please include a [mcve].

Comment: Where is the key name `studentState` defined? Your state doesn't have any such object property

Comment: Sorry, what did you mean about "the key name" ?

Comment: @agung_phe You might want to revisit how destructuring works and shorthand for object properties. `const {studentState} = useContext(StudentContext);` means create a variable called `studentState` and assign it to the value of `useContext(StudentContext).studentState`. but you state doesn't have a property called `studentState`, so it doesn't quite make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is hard to tell without a minimal reproducible example, one thing that stands out is the use of the curly braces around `{studentState}`.

If the object in the example you provided is the *entire* context value, you should not use curly braces, because this would try to extract a property called `studentState` from the context object, which does not exist in your example. Instead, you just want the entire context value:

```
const studentState = useContext(StudentContext);
```

This assumes you have previously created your `StudentContext` object somewhere and provided a value, something like this:

```
const StudentContext = React.createContext(null);


// Later, define a value 
const studentState = {
  studentId: 1,
  studentName: "Student",
  religion: {
    religionId: 1,
    religionName: "RELIGION"
  }
};


// Then in a component, render the context provider:
<StudentContext.Provider value={studentState}>
  ...
</StudentContext.Provider>
```

Read up on object destructuring in JavaScript ([this](https://wesbos.com/destructuring-objects/) is a good intro). That is what the curly braces you are using are doing.

Comment: I'm sorry not write complete reproducible example code, but the Context you write is same with my Context, I get data from web API that produce JSON format like const studentState above

Answer (score -1):

You must use condition for handling this situation..
Try this one
{ studentState.religion && studentState.religion.religionName}